# How do you use the BigInt library?

Tags: c++, libraries, dev-c++, bigint

I recently downloaded the zip file for C++ BigInt Class version 4.0. But the problem I'm having is how exactly to use it? I have several questions concerning this:

1. I unzipped the file, and all that was extracted was the application file, i.e., bigint-4-0-exe and a text document (which contained all the code within the .exe file... No instructions etc)
   Does anyone know what the headers (i.e., the #include Example.h files) are for BigInt v4.0?
2. As mentioned, after extracting the contents, there were no Example.h (or Example.a) files, but if there was, how do i link them with the Dev C++ library?
   Is it just a case of throwing the Example.h files into the same folder as the other .h files?
3. How do you link a library, in general, in Dev c++?

My goal, in general, is to divide two very large numbers  (with roughly 100 digits each). But I believe this is quite a complicated task for an amateur!

Just in case its relevant, Im using:

- Dev C++
- Windows 7
- C ++ BigInt class version 4.0 (downloaded from http://c-plus-plus-bigint-class.soft112.com/)

Comment: I have no idea why the executable is even there, but you want the [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/files/C%2B%2B%20BigInt%20Class/Version%204.0/bigint-4-0-src.zip/download)

Comment: If you have all the relevant code within the text file, why not just take and compile it?

Comment: You're right! For some reason I got the BigInt.exe zip instead of the source! The Header is there! Now, do i just add it with the other .h files? And how do i link it?

Comment: I thought it was as simple as including the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the file sample.cc which demonstrate the important features of the library. You can use BigUnsigned and BigInteger data types according to your requirements.

```
    #include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh"

    BigInteger a = 65536;
    cout << (a * a * a * a * a * a * a * a);

(prints 340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
```

Please read the code and the explanations before you run the code.